# typescript & react - why double check props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with the following props:

```
interface IChatContainerProps {
    ...
    onCollapse: Function | null;
    ...
}
```

Now, when I write the render method as follows:

```
    <div className="header__pull-right">
      {
        props.onCollapse !== null
        && (
          <button
            className="close-chat-button"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => props.onCollapse()}
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
```

it says:

```
 TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'
```

so I have to destructure the prop:

```
const {onCollapse} = props;
return (

    <div className="header__pull-right">
      {
        onCollapse
        && (
          <button
            className="close-chat-button"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => onCollapse()}
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
 )
```

why is that?  how come TS doesn't figure `props.onCollapse` automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Try check if the function is not null before use it:

```
return (
<div className="header__pull-right">
  {
    this.props.onCollapse !== null ? 
      <button
        className="close-chat-button"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => this.props.onCollapse()}
      />
    : null
  }
</div>
)
```

This occurs because your prop onCollapse can be null or a function. If it's null, you cannot execute successfully your code, so you need manually to take care if onCollapse is null